# Python/pip requires Visual C++ 14, but it is already installed

Tags: windows-7, python, python3, pip, visual-c++

I tried to install a pip package which exits with the following error message:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

But under "Programs and Features" I can see that it is installed (among other versions):

[image]

How do I make it accessible to pip? This is Windows7 and Python3.

Comment: Download and install the build tools from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/). Should be all you need at this point.

Comment: Yes, by now I've understood that "Microsoft Visual C++ 14 is required" doesn't refer to the Redistributable. The Redistributable contains code that is required to run programs written with the Visual Studio (IDE) version of that year. It does not contain the C++ compiler which is needed here. The compiler is part of the build tools. Hence the link behind the primary error message which now makes sense to me :) The naming should be "Visual C++ 14.0 Redistributable" vs "Visual C++ 14.0 Build Tools", that would be less confusing.